# Уменьшить дискретизацию графика

Tags: дискретная-математика

Как получить из графика построенного по 100 точкам - график построенный по 10 точкам с опеределенным итервалом, в который 100 точек не попадают. Тоесть уменьшить дискретизацию графика. Ткните хотя бы носом где смотреть. Попадаю только на на дискретизацию и кватнование сигнала(в гугле).

Comment: тема "Интерполяция"

Comment: скорее «Апроксимация»... но конечно тут надо угадать, что именно ТС хочет...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Интерполяция - частный случай аппроксимации...